# Internal error. MavenArchiver

Tags: java, maven

Получаю при интале вот такую ошибку. кто знает как исправить?

```
 Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.7:ear': Unable to load the mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.7:ear' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin'. A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/archiver/MavenArchiver
    org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вам не хватает некоторых зависимостей.

Найдите отсутствующие зависимости mvn dependency::tree, затем установите их вручную и постройте свой проект с опцией -o (офлайн).